# Can homosexual immigrants settle in the United States?

Tags: usa, visa

I am a Gujarati from Pakistan, 24 years old and 6 months married. I am gay. My marriage was forced upon me. I am totally fed up with my life. I don't know what to do because Pakistan does not support gays or others in the LGBT umbrella. Homosexuality is a crime here. I just want to leave my country and seek a life of my own.

Comment: Welcome to Expatriates! Your question is unclear. Are you asking if it possible culturally to settle in the U.S. as a homosexual? Well there is unquestionably an active LGBT community (with sub-communities) in the country. And while I am unaware of anything specific to immigrants, I've certainly never heard of any immigrants having unique problems (unique as in different from heterosexuals) fitting into that demographic.

Comment: Or are you asking if there are any legal impediments? Well, it's not a question on any visa application or ESTA. Same sex couples have immigrated to the United States on the basis of marriage to a U.S. citizen. And there was even a recent case where a couple had a child that was given birthright citizenship, despite the biological father not actually being a citizen. It seems unlikely you would have any impediment because of homosexuality.

Comment: If you can clarify your question, that would be very helpful. Otherwise it risks being closed.

Answer (score 2):

The USA, and other western countries, will most likely not care one bit whether you are gay or not. So you can move to the USA just like any other man or woman from Pakistan or other countries, gay or not. You will need a visa, a work visa since you want to stay permanently, just like anyone else. And that will be quite hard to get.

Comment: @MatthewBarclay Nevertheless I imagine they are at least a tiny bit more accepting of it than Pakistan.

Comment: "Not caring one bit whether you are gay or not" is an awful lot more accepting than many countries.